# Why does my Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline get stuck when left idle?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io, apache-beam

I have a streaming cloud dataflow pipeline. It reads messages from pubsub. The pipeline is an implementation of cdc(change data capture) architecture, so there is no need of event timestamps and neither it is published. When the pubsub topic/subscription is left idle for some days(2-3 days) i.e no message published for 2-3days, and then message is published on the third day, I see that the messages are not read as if the "read from pubsub" step gets stuck. The watermark doesn't progress and watermark is stuck at 2 days ago. System lag is 2 days and data freshness has crossed all limits. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

[The stats of the step image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWIdg.png)
The image was taken on 23rd september, 2020

P.S -- The only solution is to restart the dataflow, which then reads the all unacknowledged messages in subscription smoothly.

Comment: Hello @Shivanshu, did you check the Dataflow job logs for this problematic step seeking for some suspicious events?

Comment: @Nick_Kh - I checked the logs of the step. Nothing is available in the logs as it is the first step in the pipeline and a simple step of pubsubIO.readfromsubscription . What I doubt is, the watermark gets stuck because dataflow isnt able to compute the watermark as no event-timestamp is published. Can that be the reason?

Comment: Do you have Expiration period [adjusted](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#using_subscription_properties) to your subscription?

Comment: No, the subscription never expires. @Nick_kh

Comment: Maybe it's because late data coming with timestamps outside the window range for the particular watermark, check out this [chapter](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#managing-late-data) for more details?